# UICollectionView inside Static TableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uicollectionview

I've seen many tutorials online pertaining to embedding UICollectionViews inside dynamic table view cells and subclassing the collection view to set the delegate but I was wondering if the process is any different for static table view cells.

I tried following the example [here](https://github.com/DahanHu/DHCollectionTableView) but I couldn't quite follow it through because it seems overly complicated with little to no explanation. Would anyone mind outlining the basic steps I need to go through with in order to get my collection view to work?

Here's my code so far:

```
class FeaturedController: UITableViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    popularCollectionView.dataSource = self
    popularCollectionView.delegate = self
}

//MARK: Popular Events Collection View
    @IBOutlet weak var popularCollectionView: UICollectionView!

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 4
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = popularCollectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("popular", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UICollectionViewCell

        return cell
    }
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you know how to add a collection view to a dynamic table view cell, adding it to a static one would be far easier. You don't need to sub class anything at all (but doing so could be a nice idea). Under the hood, a static table view is nothing more than just a normal table view that having support from the hosting `UITableViewController` to set what you have layout in the Interface Builder automatically. So, here's how to do it:

1. Dragging a Collection View from the Object Library in the Interface Builder and place it in the cell you want.
2. Make sure the Table View is hosted by a Table View Controller.
3. Set constraints or layout the Collection View in the cell.
4. Set the Collection View's dataSource to the hosted Table View Controller.
5. Adding `UICollectionViewDataSource` conformance to the Table View Controller.
6. Implement `UICollectionViewDataSource`'s methods, namely `collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:` and `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` in the `UITableViewController`.

If you know how to work with a `UITableView` or `UICollectionView` in general, this should not be hard to follow.

**UPDATE**
Your code looks like it should have worked.
So, you should check whether:

1. You've really set the class of the Table View Controller to your `FeaturedController` class.
2. You really have wired the Collection View in the Interface Builder to `popularCollectionView`.
3. You already have a prototype Collection View Cell with the identifier `popular`. Although, it should crash if you haven't done so.
4. In the IB, you have already set the Table View to be static.

I have a small example I did here

[image: Interface Builder]

The orange view is the Collection View with the greenish view the prototype Collection View Cell with identifier `myCell`.

[image: Data Source]

And then I set my view controller to the Collection View's data source. But you could set it in the code too like you did too.

Then I implement the data source methods below.

```
@interface ViewController () <UICollectionViewDataSource>

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 20;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"myCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}

@end
```

And this is the result:

[image: result]

Comment: Still nothing is showing up but there are no errors. Could it be my constraints?

Comment: Have you set up the data source? You can look at the view debugger to see if the collection view is really there or not.

Comment: The collection view is there but none of the cells are (I checked in the view debugging mode. I'm updating the post to show what I have

Comment: I've updated my answer. Basically, try checking whether you have properly set the outlet and the view controller class.

Comment: I've checked and rechecked everything but nothing shows up. I'm just going to delete everything and restart. Thanks for your time though

Answer (score 0):

For TableView **static cells**:

In your view controller where you have connected collection view, add in view did load delegates and data source for the collection view, this will add the delegates to tableview **cell**, if you do with storyboard, you are connecting it wrong because delegates and datasource has to be inside cell initialization.

```
@IBOutlet weak var quotesCollectionView: UICollectionView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    quotesCollectionView.delegate = self
    quotesCollectionView.dataSource = self
}
```

For TableView **dynamic cells**:

```
class QuotesTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

// MARK: Properties

@IBOutlet weak var quotesCollectionView: UICollectionView!

// MARK: Initialization

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    quotesCollectionView.delegate = self
    quotesCollectionView.dataSource = self
   }
}
```